# UIActivityViewController's SMS window becomes partially transparent

Tags: ios, sms, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm seeing a very strange UI effect when calling UIActivityViewController and the user subsequently selects the Messages option.

I've reduced the code in question down to the bare details:

```
NSArray *activityItems = @[@"Hello!"];
UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

When the user selects the Messages app, the subview containing the "To:" field has a gradient background:

[image: Initial view]

The user then begins to type (nothing surprising here):

[image: User typing]

And then the user deletes what they've just typed - causing the "To:" view to go transparent.  What shows through is UI from my app.

[image: After user deletes what they've typed]

There's no way to get the "To:" view back, although typing does work (nothing displays).

The code above works fine in a dummy app.  I'm sure something in this app is causing the issue, but I've been unable to find the cause (or even understand what could cause this).  This is in a UITableViewController but I've put the same code into a plain UIViewController with the same results.  I've wrapped in a dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()...) call, set the statusBar to be visible, etc.  No change.  Any suggestions appreciated!

**Solution**

The culprit was a wacky UIAppearance selector on UINavigationBar:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[self whitePixelImage] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

where "whitePixelImage" was exactly what you might expect:

```
-(UIImage *)whitePixelImage {
    return [self imageWithColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
}

-(UIImage *)imageWithColor:(UIColor *)color {
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [color CGColor]);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

My suspicion is the one pixel size was the issue, but due to design changes to the app no longer requiring this selector I was quite happy to remove the whole darned thing.

Comment: Does this happen on device or simulator? Quick Googling says UIActivityViewController has issues in the simulator (I'm guessing because it relies on a bunch of external, device-only services).

Comment: The Simulator has no Messages app, so this is device-only.  I should also add this is iOS 7.  The app is iOS 7-only, and I haven't tested this feature on a device with iOS 8.

Comment: I've also tried presenting from super, self.navigationController, and even from [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController without change.

Comment: SOLVED!  The app had a weird UIAppearance setting for UINavigationBar.  Removing that solved the problem.  I'll edit my question with details of the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a wacky UIAppearance selector on UINavigationBar.  Specifics of that selector added to the bottom of the question.  Hopefully this will be helpful to someone.